# add a object to a array in my class

Tags: oop, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I want to add an `object` (from a different class) to an `array` in my class.
When I try to do that I get this

> error:  0xC0000005: Access violation writing location
>   0x0000000000000000

I create the object (to be added) in the main function and I use the push method in the main function to add this object to my `Parking_Lot` class.

My code:

```
void Parking_Lot::push(Cars const &car)
{
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm Today = *localtime(&t);
    if (is_full())
    {
        printf("Parking lot is full!!\n");
        return;
    }
    if (Today.tm_hour < OpeningT.tm_hour && Today.tm_hour > ClosingT.tm_hour)
    {
        printf("Parking lot is now closed!!\n");
        printf("Opening time: from %02d:%02d to %02d:%02d\n", OpeningT.tm_hour, OpeningT.tm_min, ClosingT.tm_hour, ClosingT.tm_min);
    }
    else if (Today.tm_hour == OpeningT.tm_hour || Today.tm_hour == ClosingT.tm_hour)
    {
        if(Today.tm_min > OpeningT.tm_min || Today.tm_min < ClosingT.tm_min) Lot[front++] = car;
        else
        {
            printf("Parking lot is now closed!!\n");
            printf("Opening time: from %02d:%02d to %02d:%02d\n", OpeningT.tm_hour, OpeningT.tm_min, ClosingT.tm_hour, ClosingT.tm_min);
        }
    }
    else if(Today.tm_hour > OpeningT.tm_hour && Today.tm_hour < ClosingT.tm_hour) Lot[front++] = car;
}
```

where the `car` is the object I want to add and the `Lot` is the array in my class that I want to add the object to.

The constructor of my class:

```
Parking_Lot::Parking_Lot(int s)
{
    Cars* Lot = new Cars[s+1];
    size = s;
    front = 0;
}
```

What am i doing wrong here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your constructor:

```
Parking_Lot::Parking_Lot(int s)
{
    Cars* Lot = new Cars[s+1];
    size = s;
    front = 0;
}
```

You define a *new* and *separate* variable `Lot` inside the constructor. It will *not* be related to any possible member variable you might have with the same name.

You need to initialize the member variable instead:

```
Parking_Lot::Parking_Lot(int s)
{
    Lot = new Cars[s+1];
    size = s;
    front = 0;
}
```